# Change location of a graph

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

I have 3 graphs and I want to put one of them to another place on the local host screen. But I'm a beginner on php and I have no idea is it possible or how can I do that. Can you give me any advice for it ? How can I do that ? Thanks.

[image: This is what I want to do]

My HTML codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
      text: "RR Interval Time Series"  
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [
<?PHP
    foreach($arr as $key => $v){
        $output[] = "{ x: " . $x[$key] . ", y: " . $v . " }";
    }
    echo implode(",\n", $output);
?>
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

var data = <?php echo json_encode($wshort, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

data = data.map(function (row, index) {
    return {
        x: index,
        y: row
    };
});
var chart2 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {
    title: {
        text: "FFT Results"
    },

    data: [{
        type: "line",

        dataPoints: data
    }]
});

var chart3 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer3",
    {
      title:{
      text: "Poincare Plot"  
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "scatter",
        dataPoints: [

<?PHP
    foreach($pointy as $key1 => $v1){
        $output1[] = "{ x: " . $pointx[$key1] . ", y: " . $v1 . " }";
    }
    echo implode(",\n", $output1);
?>

        ]
      }
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
    chart2.render();
    chart3.render();
  }
  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 200px; width: 70%;">
  </div>
  <div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 200px; width: 70%;">
  </div>
  <div id="chartContainer3" style="height: 300px; width: 30%;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to change position of "chartContainer3". Should I do something with div style ?

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with PHP.  Probably HTML, CSS, or Javascript (or some combination of those).  Regardless, it is impossible to say without seeing the related code.

Comment: I understand, I'll check HTML and CSS for it. Thanks Patrick

Comment: I added my html codes, can you check please ?

Comment: Can't you simply put the `chartContainer3` div above the `chartContainer` div?  If you don't like the order they're in, just move them.  Did you try?

Comment: I can but it's not what I want. I want chartContainer3 up and swiped right.

Comment: So it should be just first and float: right